# ASP.NET MVC5 Html.Beginform not calling action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I had my submit form working from my razor file to a controller, then from the controller to my remote database. but now i don't even think the controller class is being called.

Here is my view:

```
@model InputEvent

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Portal/Controllers/MyEvent"))
{
    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-xs="">
        <label>Title</label>                    
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.title)
    </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container class="md-block">
        <label>Address</label>                        
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.address)
    </md-input-container>

    <md-button class="md-raised">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </md-button>
}
```

with my model:

```
public class InputEvent
{
    public string title;
    public string address;
}
```

And my controller with the database connection:

```
namespace Portal.Controllers
{  
public class MyEventController : Controller
{      
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(InputEvent y)
    {            
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("mydbstring");
        string myTitle = y.title;
        string myAddress = y.address;

        conn.Open();                         

        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
        comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO event(title, address) VALUES(@title, @address)";

        //comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", myTitle);
        //comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", myAddress);

        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", "test_title");
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", "test_address");
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();

        return View();
    }        
}
}
```

Am i not calling my controller correctly? or is my sql command invalid?

**EDIT:** I just checked my database again over an hour later, and i have multiple rows with "test_title" and "test_address" in there. i guess my code works, but it is VERY delayed. This might not be the best place to ask, but does anyone have any idea why it could be so delayed inserting into the DB?

Comment: I'm not sure how your routing is set up, but I think I would expect to see `Html.BeginForm("Save", "MyEvent")` instead of the explicit controller path. What does the browser show in the dev console when submitting the form?

Comment: Watch your browser's network monitor. Are the requests successful?

Comment: when i change it to just "MyEvent" instead of "Portal/Controllers/MyEvent" it tries to take me to the URL: "MyEvent/Save". I don't think that is what i want. The console has no errors, it just says: Navigated to http://localhost:8000/App/Add_Event

Comment: You need to replace `"Portal/Controllers/MyEvent"` with the actual name of the controller - i.e. `"MyEvent"`

Comment: All requests in the network monitor are successful.

Comment: If using `Html.BeginForm("Save", "MyEvent")` is not working then you have other errors in your code that you have not shown us. And assuming the GET method is `public ActionResult Save()` then you do not even need the parameters - it can be just `Html.BeginForm()`

Comment: Based on your edit you should delete the question (and ask a new question about your other issue)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the server-side code looks like the code below. Note the `[HttpPost]` attribute. While the default for client-side form is Post, `HttpGet` is the default for the server-side. So you would have to explicitly say you want a `HttpPost` on the server-side. Do the following steps. Note `Save` method has two overloads and also one with `HttpGet` and the other with `HttpPost`. When you are done, put a break point on the method with the `HttpPost` attribute and post the form. You will see that the model will be hydrated.

Step 1

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "MyEvent", FormMethod.Post))
    {
       <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-xs="">
        <label>Title</label>                    
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.title)
       </md-input-container>

      <md-input-container class="md-block">
        <label>Address</label>                        
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.address)
      </md-input-container>

      <md-button class="md-raised">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
      </md-button>
   }
```

Step 2

```
 public class MyEventController : Controller
 {

     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Save(InputEvent model)
     {     
         // Consider refining the implementation to use Stored Procedures or an ORM e.g. Entity Framework. 
         // It helps secure your app. Application security advice.    

         MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("mydbstring"); 
         conn.Open();                        

         MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
         comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO event(title, address) VALUES(" + model.title + "," + model.address + ")";  
         comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

         conn.Close();    
         return View();
     }

     [HttpGet]
     public ActionResult Save()
     {                
         return View();
     }
 }
```

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke , I used the word "Ensure",  because @user3329046 could have it here on StackOverflow and not in source code.

Comment: @JuliusDepulla It's pretty obvious he has got it when he says "my controller". It's just copy and pasted from his source code.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `FormMethod.Post` as a third parameter... your action method is specting a Post and not a Get.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "MyEvent", FormMethod.Post)){
  ....
}
```

Comment: The default is `FormMethod.Post` - this is not necessary at all (refer [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String%29))

Comment: As Stephen said, i'm pretty sure `FormMethod.Post` is default. i tried adding it and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your code is working now. However, you should not be returning a view from a POST method the way you are. You should use [PRG](http://sampathloku.blogspot.ca/2013/05/how-to-use-prg-pattern-with-aspnet-mvc-4.html) pattern. Read that link so you are aware of the issues your code can cause. I know that is for MVC 4 but the pattern is the same regardless of the version of MVC.